# Removing post category base giving Error 404

Tags: categories, permalinks

I have a WordPress website and i am dealing with a very rare kind of issue.

I want to change my base category for blog posts:-

My current post url is `https://www.example.com/media/press-release/2020/post-url`

For post url i have used the permalink: `/media/%category%/%postname%`

My current category url is `https://www.example.com/category/press-release/2020`

I want to replace: `category` to `media` in the above category url.

I have tried adding '.' in category base.

I have tried adding `media` in category, by this category url works fine but post url is giving `Error 404`

I have also tried the method with Yoast SEO `taxonomies` that is not working for me.

Final Results needed:

Post Url `https://www.example.com/media/press-release/2020/post-url`

Post Category: `https://www.example.com/media/press-release/2020`